# Auto-update of Java application converted to a Windows installable

Tags: java, windows, deployment, auto-update

I found a lot of discussions around this point but speaking either of a Java program running from the jar (in this case it is easy to replace it) or a C# application (I do not have knowledge on C#).

I use a tool (install4j, ..) to generate an installable file for Windows from the jar of my java swing application. My product installed and running on Windows should be able to "auto-update" itself, so I must have a component in my application that checks online if a newer version was to download and put in place of the currently executing.

I do not know how my application is installed in Windows (where are put the files? in one place? ... ) So what can I do to replace the current version being run with a new version (probably from a new installable file télchargé in this case) ? what's the best way?

how can I hide the questions like "do you accept ...?" and keep the original configuration during the update?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem for me is that my client wants/does not necessarily install java

Use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to ensure the client has a suitable minimum version of Java installed.  Then deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to provide auto-update.  I realize you don't want to make the client install Java, but you might be making the client install Windows if you make an executable.  You'll typically lose more users by forcing them to install **Windows,** than by forcing them to install Java.

Now, when I give this advice to some people, they say words to the effect:

> But my client only uses Windows OS!  It will never be run on Mac OS or Linux/Unix.

And to that I would point out:

> OK fine, but it seems yo are trying to make a left-hand turn at a right turn only intersection.  If you need to turn left, you should have done that 6 blocks back.

What I mean by that is:  Windows has its own languages and IDEs specialized for Windows.  Being a language designed for Windows would mean it has:

- Better ways to delve into the OS.  Java keeps its functionality to a core set of functions that can be reliably supported across all major platforms. Anything beyond that requires native code.
- Faster development time for any GUI elements.  Java GUIs need to be designed using layout managers which are harder to learn and not conducive to Drag-and-Drop GUI design, which can be much faster.
- A Windows based language probably has a slew of APIs and tools for providing auto-update, or if not, more free or reasonably priced 3rd party APIs for that.

> ..there are customers who imposed to not install java..

There is something you don't seem to understand.  [The GNU Compiler for the Java<sup>TM</sup> Programming Language](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) compiles code to natives.  That is the *only* way to 'turn a Java app. into an executable.  The GNU Compiler..

> ..supports *most* of the 1.4 libraries plus ***some*** 1.5 additions.

It does not even claim to support all of Java **1.3.**

There are other utilities to install Java apps. with a *private JRE.*  It might seem the JRE installation is invisible to the average user.  But the power user would not be fooled.  E.G.

### Look and Feel

A Swing based app. using the Native Pluggable Look and Feel might look 'much like' a Windows app., but many people can still tell the difference.  Swing does particular components differently to native Windows components (most notably `JFileChooser`, but there are others), and although the rest of the components look a lot like Windows equivalents, they are not *exactly* the same.   Even the AWT based `FileDialog` looks different to the Windows file dialog.

### Security

If the user has a problem with their PC and decides to kill a misbehaving app. they might type the following command sequence to bring up the Task Manager: 
 
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> 
Even most non-power users know that key combo.
Now, let's say I am a potential customer that thinks 'Java is insecure - I don't want it on my PC'. Your app. comes along, I look at the box, no mention of Java. Good so far. Look at the one or two screenshots of it on the back of the box - looks much like a Windows app., OK.

So I fork out $24.95 for it.

I get it back to the office, install it and run, thinking:

> It has an odd feel to it, but I'm too busy now, I'll check it out later.

Then I go surfing off to the net, visit a site infected with malware, and that malware causes MS Word to lock up.  So I go to kill MS Word in preparation for restarting it, but..  As I'm scrolling down the available processes I notice..  **Java is running.**

What the huh..?

I immediately kill every Java process and see.. your app. drop off screen.

Let's go even further to assume the Malware (that is still running) goes on to cause $2000 damage to my hardware & wipes the client database I spent 3 years putting together ($50,000 loss).

I would get on the phone immediately to my lawyer and take you to court, suing you for the sum total of $1,052,024.95.

Later, in court:

> **Judge:** What is the million collars for?
>
> **Me:**  Mental stress, your honor.  The defendant lied to me and *now I have become paranoid.*  Since that malware was installed, I've lost my business, my home, my wife **and** my peace of mind.  It has caused me to become deeply depressed and I am experiencing suicidal thoughts.

Who do *you* think the judge is going to side with?  Do you really think you can *prove* that your app. was in no way responsible for the problem?

Sure, you can put a disclaimer on the box:

> No claims of responsibility, use at own risk.

But there are any number of US states as well as other entire countries, that will toss that entire End User Lisense Agreement right out the window and *hold you responsible.*

What I'm getting at, is that you are taking a huge legal risk to pretend that a Java app. is anything but a Java app.  So ***don't*** do that!

Comment: Thank you, but the product is already ready and not easy to do it again in C #, and there are customers who imposed to not install java, so I'm on the point of provide them the product installable form and that they can update automatically.

Comment: You seem determined to keep asking this question until you hear the answer you *want to hear.*  I will not be giving you any help on that.  Instead, I have expanded my answer to include a section on why you should *reconsider your approach..*  And that is the final thing I have to say on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I am also very keen to know that, as per my knowledge, I deployed my application using JNLP (java network launch protocol) after signing your jar file, Client's jar itself replace with the newer version.

The confirmation question "Do you Accept" in JNLP is because of the certificate windows security and JVM certification didn't recognize that.

here is tutorial for JNLP

```
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/
```

Comment: The problem for me is that my client wants/does not necessarily install java

Comment: I am waiting for any answer too.

Comment: @Sarz  If you expect any answer you should ask your own question, rather than put it as an answer to this question..

Comment: i shared my knowledge about auto-update maybe it will help some, and now m also attached to the post.